# Generate a non-repeating random number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, numbers

How do I ensure that I don't get a repeat of a random number? Right now, this isn't working. I'm using a local array to store previous results.

```
getUniqueRandomNumber(x){
     var index;
     var viewedIndices = [];
     index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (x));
     if(viewedIndices.includes(index)) 
     {
       viewedIndices.push(index);
       this.getUniqueRandomNumber(x);
     }
     else { 
       console.log(index);
       return index;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Declare `index` as a global variable?

Comment: Why are you doing this recursively?

Comment: I want the user to click a button once only to call this function, and let the function ensure a non-duplicate appears

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 mistakes, oné is the array inside the function this cleared for each try, and then there is wrong logic ending up in an infinite loop.

```
const usedIndexes = [];    
function getUniqueRandomNumber(x) {
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (x));
  if (usedIndexes.includes(index)) {
    return this.getUniqueRandomNumber(x);
  } else { 
    console.log(index);
    usedIndexes.push(index);
    return index;
  }
}
```

Also, I would think about using `Set`, in this situation instead of the array.

```
const usedIndexes = new Set();    
function getUniqueRandomNumber(max, min = 0) {
  const newNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
  if (usedIndexes.has(newNumber)) {
    return this.getUniqueRandomNumber(max, min);
  } else { 
    usedIndexes.add(newNumber);
    return newNumber;
  }
}
```

I have also edited variables names to better reflect their actual use and added a minimum for a random number.

Comment: This works! Thanks!! How can i refine this to use Set() instead? Also how can i check for when 'x' is reached. So if x=20, after 20 runs of this function, it exceeds max call stack. How can i check for this and output a message to say "no more"?

Comment: There seems to be an other problem then, how many numbers are you trying to get it to work with? Which ones?

Comment: It can be any 2 or 100. this logic:  if (chosenNumbers.size === x) {
      throw new Error('No more uniques!'); doesn't work. it just hits max call stack

Comment: The logic does: I want a pool of 20 random numbers if my pool has 20 numbers, I know for sure, I can't create any new unique numbers in that pool.

Answer (score 5):

You need to make `viewedIndicies` *persistent*, so that further calls of `getUniqueRandomNumber` can see elements previously added. Rather than keeping track of the indicies, it would probably be easier to keep track of just the plain *numbers* chosen. You can use a Set instead of an array for less computational complexity (`.has` is `O(1)`, `.includes` is `O(N)`).

```js
const makeGetUniqueRandomNumber = (x) => {
  const chosenNumbers = new Set();
  return () => {
    if (chosenNumbers.size === x) {
      throw new Error('No more uniques!');
    }
    let num;
    do {
      num = Math.floor(Math.random() * x);
    } while (chosenNumbers.has(num));
    chosenNumbers.add(num);
    return num;
  };
};

const getRand5 = makeGetUniqueRandomNumber(5);
console.log(
  getRand5(),
  getRand5(),
  getRand5(),
  getRand5(),
  getRand5()
);
try {
  getRand5();
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}

const anotherGetRand5 = makeGetUniqueRandomNumber(5);
console.log(
  anotherGetRand5(),
  anotherGetRand5(),
  anotherGetRand5(),
  anotherGetRand5(),
  anotherGetRand5()
);
```

You may also generate the whole array of random numbers ahead of time, and then `splice` each time another is chosen, but that'll be inefficient when the number of possibilities is large but you only need a few random numbers. The right choice depends on the proportion of unique numbers needed in one session to the size of the random range.

If developing in an ancient environment which doesn't understand ES6 (ES2015) syntax, then you can use an array instead of a Set, and pass the code through Babel:

```js
"use strict";

var makeGetUniqueRandomNumber = function makeGetUniqueRandomNumber(x) {
  var chosenNumbers = [];
  return function () {
    if (chosenNumbers.length === x) {
      throw new Error('No more uniques!');
    }

    var num;

    do {
      num = Math.floor(Math.random() * x);
    } while (chosenNumbers.includes(num));

    chosenNumbers.push(num);
    return num;
  };
};

var getRand5 = makeGetUniqueRandomNumber(5);
console.log(getRand5(), getRand5(), getRand5(), getRand5(), getRand5());

try {
  getRand5();
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}

var anotherGetRand5 = makeGetUniqueRandomNumber(5);
console.log(anotherGetRand5(), anotherGetRand5(), anotherGetRand5(), anotherGetRand5(), anotherGetRand5());
```

Comment: Good job with non recursiveness

Comment: Press "Run code snippet" in the answer - you can see for yourself that it outputs the random numbers as desired. `makeGetUniqueRandomNumber` is a function which returns a function, and then you need to call that returned function to get a random number. It sounds like you aren't calling the returned function.

Comment: Could the downvoter explain what isn't useful about my answer? If I made a mistake, I'll be happy to fix it :)

Comment: Ah, i don't need a set of random numbers!! I just need ONE (perhaps i should have put that in OP). I need just one number in the range [0 to x) that hasn't appeared before and that once all those numbers have been used up, message that there's no more uniques

Comment: The Set is being used to ensure that only uniques are returned. If you don't use a Set, you'll need an array (but a Set is more appropriate when indicies don't matter). If you don't use either a Set or an array (or some similar data structure), you won't be able to identify unique values

Comment: Does it throw a syntax error? You should consider using a modern development environment, ES6+ - ES5 (which doesn't understand sets or `const`s) was released in 2009, which is a century ago in programming terms. Any recent web browser should support ES6 just fine (basically, anything but IE11)

Comment: Ok, I transpiled the code with Babel, the second snippet is in ES5

Comment: `makeGetUniqueRandomNumber` is a function that returns a function. Every time you call `makeGetUniqueRandomNumber` a new collection is made, and calls to the returned function return non-repeated elements, allowing you to get random non-repeating elements *multiple times* (like in the snippet). It returns a function, so you have to call that returned function in order to generate a new random number.

Comment: Yeah, thats not what i'm after. I need a single unique number to be generated, when i run that function, that hasn't appeared in any instance when ive ran that function before (i.e. clicked that button before). Let's put this to bed

Comment: Then just call `makeGetUniqueRandomNumber` once, and you'll have a function that'll return unique numbers. If you really only need *one* such choosing function, you can remove `makeGetUniqueRandomNumber` and just declare the function as what gets `return`ed in the snippet, but that's not flexible and probably of less value.

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because every time you call **getUniqueRandomNumber** it re-initializes your **viewedIndices** array to empty array. So to make your code work declare this array above the function call.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want the code you wrote to work or do you want a better solution? Picking random numbers until you don't get a repeat is a recipe for disaster down the line as your program stalls for several seconds trying to find a number that hasn't been used. Sure if you're only asking for a few numbers maybe it won't take forever but then the code sits in your code base and 5 years from now someone else is using it not knowing there is a time bomb in the code. Imagine there are 10000 elements in the array and 9999 have been picked. It could easily take 1 million re-tries before it ends up picking the one unused index.

The code appears to be choosing indices with variable names like `index` and `viewedIndices`

One way to pick random elements is just  just remove then from the array at random. If you need to make copy of the array

```js
const array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];

while (array.length) {
  const ndx = Math.random() * array.length | 0;
  const elem = array.splice(ndx, 1)[0];
  console.log(elem);
}
```

Note: using `Math.random() * value | 0` to get a random 0 -> positive integer is faster than `Math.floor(Math.random() * value)` as `|` is an operator, not a function attached to the `Math` object that has to be checked on every call to see if it has been replaced.